# psql/heroku connection refused, does not accept TCP/IP connections on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, psql, tcp

I've been trying to run `heroku run python manage.py migrate` on my Django app but I keep getting this error message:

```
    psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried and tested every possible solution: editing my `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` so `psql` listens to all hosts and ports, temporarily turning off my firewall and antivirus software, restarting the `psql` service after allowing TCP access in my firewall to port `5432`; none of which have worked. However, when I run `show port` and `show listen_addresses` on psql, they show `5432` and `*` respectively.

I'm running the `heroku` command on Command Prompt, but I have successfully pushed my local database to `DATABASE_URL` via Ubuntu 16.04 on Windows (though I did have to specify `PGHOST` and `PGPORT`). I tried defining those two on Ubuntu as well as I run `migrate`, but my connection was still refused too.

While running `psql` on Ubuntu, `netstat` showed this:

```
    Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
    TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         PCname:56449         ESTABLISHED
```

I'm lost on what else to do.

Thanks!